Restoration of a deeply weathered deck
I have a weathered deck that I was hoping to restore this year.  It was previously stained/sealed with the same Armstrong-Clark product I am using.  I washed the deck, sanded deck boards with 80 grit paper and applied stain.  Immediately black patchy areas appeared on my test section.  Hoping for advice on how to proceed.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I believe this should be considered perfectly normal (and possibly unavoidable). If it's what I think it is it's unavoidable because it's not practical to sand the boards deeply enough to get to wood unaffected by weathering. If you do have the leeway to sand more (and can stomach doing lots more sanding LOL) you can try it and see if it lessens the problem acceptably or it goes away entirely.

Looks perfectly reasonable to me. Don't forget, the pics you see in magazines and on the can are either of brand new material that has been specifically selected and prepared for taking said pictures, or has been altered after the pics have been taken. Wood is a natural product that continues to "live" even after being milled into boards. Celebrate the differences, don't try to cover them up. If you do want a perfectly even coloring, paint it. (Be aware, painting a deck has other, serious considerations, too.)

Thanks for the replies! This is my first exterior deck restoration effort. I was worried the darker regions were a reflection of inadequate preparation or some other error.  I’m very much content knowing that it’s variation in the wood itself and can be looked at as acceptable.
